# Does Spring 5 Webflux has its own way of implementing SNS + SQS?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, amazon-sns, spring-webflux

Does Spring 5 Webflux has its own way of implementing SNS + SQS? We are using Spring 5 Webflux to implement a microservice and would like to know if it provides its own way of SNS and SQS implementation.

I googled but nothing came up specific to Spring 5 Webflux, so would like to confirm before doing the old way.

This is one article that I came across: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-aws-messaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Spring Boot SNS/SQS and it worked fine.

Comment: How do you handle transforming sns messages?
According to https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/issues/141, it does not really seem to be possible